# How can I set ScrollView as the parent of an RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to the android app development now i am designing an app,in that i have an activity which has two parallel edit text fields like shown in the image

[image]

(contains 15 sets of edit text fields). I used relative layout. I want to add a vertical scroll view because some text fields go out from the screen. I studied few tutorials and all of them use linear layouts to add scroll view.

Here is my layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here how can I add scroll view without changing two parallel edit text fields. Please guide me.
Thank you!

Comment: Solved by adding ScrollView as the root of the screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a ScrollView as the root of your screen. ScrollView should have a single child layout that contains all the children..

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- All your views -->

     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" />
</RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```